# Can't start redis as a service

Tags: redis, centos

We're doing a big server migration on Azure and I want to reinstall our Redis version on the new server to match.
2 environments, Preproduction & Production. For the Production installation, no problem but with the same installation script, I can't start Redis as a service on our Preproduction server.

Here's the script I use:

```
wget http://cbs.centos.org/kojifiles/packages/redis/2.8.19/2.el7/x86_64/redis-2.8.19-2.el7.x86_64.rpm

yum localinstall -y redis-2.8.19-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
mkdir -p /data/redis/db /data/redis/logs
chown -R redis:redis /data/redis
mv /etc/redis.conf /etc/redis.conf.origin
chown redis:redis /etc/redis.conf
```

After that, I try to start the service and here's the error I've got in journalctl:

```
Aug 08 11:49:20 #new_server# redis-server[25441]: *** FATAL CONFIG FILE ERROR ***
Aug 08 11:49:20 #new_server# redis-server[25441]: Reading the configuration file, at line 7
Aug 08 11:49:20 #new_server# redis-server[25441]: >>> 'logfile /data/redis/logs/redis.log'
Aug 08 11:49:20 #new_server# redis-server[25441]: Can't open the log file: Permission denied
Aug 08 11:49:20 #new_server# systemd[1]: redis.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
```

I also try to give all access to the folder /data/redis/ (chmod -R 777) but I've got the same error in journalctl.

I also do a general update (excluding the redis package) but nothing change.

I don't know what to do to resolve that.

CentOS version: CentOS Linux release 7.5.1804 (Core)
Azure VM Size: Standard A2 v2 (2 vcpus, 4 GB memory)

> **UPDATE**

Ok, I just found that if I change the VM size to a *Standard A4m v2 (4 vcpus, 32 GB memory)*, the start started correctly.
I don't know if it the size or the restart of the VM that cause the service to start correctly.

I'm going to test it to the second server (with the new VM size) to see if it's the size or the restart that causes that.

> **UPDATE**

Ok, after another installation, I know now that it comes from the restart. The Redis service started correctly after a restart.
I don't know why though.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you don't have the standard log file directory: should be `/var/log/redis/`.

For me, the issue was that `ProtectHome` was set to `yes`, preventing the log file in `/home/log/redis/` to work.

So the issue lies down in the `systemd` configuration file, as the default protects the system a lot (that's good, but debugging is quite hard!).